# Transform GML to Geometry (PostGIS) in GeoKettle

Tags: geometry, xml, gml, geokettle

How can I transform GML (saved in XML file) to Geometry type?

I've noticed function 'Geometry from GML' in Calculator but it needs string value with GML. Is there any way to extract it from XML file? 'Get data from XML' component can give me values stored in node but not whole node.